# Bootstrap's data-toggle and JQuery code not working together

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use this HTML code to toggle a modal (id = confirm-order). It is working as it should.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-order" class="orderbtn">
```

However, when I add this JQuery code to hide or show a popup div (class = floatorder), the data-toggle is no longer working. But the JQuery is.

```
$(".floatorder").toggle(localStorage.menuWindow==="true")
$(".orderbtn").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  localStorage.menuWindow= $(".floatorder").toggle().is(":visible")
});
```

The console is not throwing an error ...

Comment: You should pass to the .toogle()  function two params, please read docs https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: The toggle function is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass to the .toogle() function two params, please read docs api.jquery.com/toggle